# ORACLE SQL query to get rows of intervals of 30 minutes based on two hours

Tags: sql, oracle, intervals

I need to do a query that give me rows of 30 minutes of intervals based on two hours, start_hour and end_hour.
I have a table, in this table i have this columns "start_hour and end_hour".
Assuming that i have this
| start_hour | end_hour |
|  09:00AM   |  08:00PM |
I need a query that gave a result like this.
| intervals |
|  09:00AM  |
|  09:30AM  |
|  10:00AM  |
|  10:30AM  |
|  11:00AM  |
|  11:30AM  |
|  12:00AM  |
|  12:30AM  |
...
...
...
|  07:30PM  |
|  08:00PM  |
And the rows need to finish in te end_hour value i have in the table, as shown in the example.
Someone can help me how to do it, i tried rounding the start_hour, but i don't have any result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit clunky and will take a bit of editing based on your specific needs, but it's a very slightly modified bit of code I used a few years back that should work as a solid starting point for you:

```
select to_char(time_slot,'HH:MIPM') 
  from (select trunc(to_date('05/23/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'))+(rownum-1)*(30/24/60) time_slot 
          from dual 
          connect by level <= (24*2))
 where to_char(time_slot,'HH24:MI') between
    --start_hour
    '09:00'
    and
    --end hour
    '20:00';

OUTPUT
09:00AM
09:30AM
10:00AM
10:30AM
11:00AM
11:30AM
12:00PM
12:30PM
01:00PM
01:30PM
02:00PM
02:30PM
03:00PM
03:30PM
04:00PM
04:30PM
05:00PM
05:30PM
06:00PM
06:30PM
07:00PM
07:30PM
08:00PM
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i really hope this help with my issue, as soon as i have obtained the solution i want, I will notify you how i do that.